# Execute bash commands via Java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, runtime, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I have such command:

```
top -bn1 | grep \"Cpu(s)\" | sed \"s/.*, *\\([0-9.]*\\)%* id.*/\\1/\" | awk '{print 100 - $1}
```

I tried to run it with `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime`, but I get nothing. Why?

Comment: or get top:unknown  param '|'

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.